# Oracle WCC ServiceHandler not running

Tags: java, oracle-ucm

I'm creating a component to add some AJAX style functionality for **Oracle WCC 11G**

The Front-End Works successfully and is leveraging [Bex Huff's Oracle UCM Jquery Plugin](http://bexhuff.com/2010/06/oracle-ucm-jquery-plugin).

I've created a ServiceHandler for **DocService** ***PREPARE_BASKET*** *prepareTopicEdits()*.  However it never fires.

**Content Basket** defines *PREPARE_BASKET* like so:

```
<tr>
    <td>PREPARE_BASKET</td>
    <td>DocService
        17
        REDIRECT_TEMPLATE
        null
        null<br>
        null</td>
    <td>3:prepareTopicEdits:::null
        3:checkBasketLimit::0:null
        3:prepareRedirect:IdcService=SHOW_BASKET:0:null</td>
</tr>
```

So I Wired up my **ServiceHandlder** Like so:

```
  <tr>
     <td>DocService</td><td>com.foo.ecm.ajaxValidator.ContentBasketHandler</td><td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>PREPARE_BASKET</td><td>com.foo.ecm.ajaxValidator.ContentBasketHandler</td><td>10</td>
  </tr>
```

The Table is listed in the merge rules in the *componentName.hda* file

`ContentBasketHandler extends ServiceHandler` in the  `com.foo.ecm.ajaxValidator` package.

`prepareTopicEdits` is defined in the class like so:

```
public void prepareTopicEdits() throws DataException, ServiceException
{
  Report.trace(TRACE_SECTION, "in prepareTopicEdits()", null);

  //rest of method

  //pass the call up the chain
  m_service.doCodeEx("prepareTopicEdits", this);
}
```

When I run look at the System Audit Log (with verbose Logging) my message never appears.

So why doesn't my ServiceHandler method fire, and how can I get it to run properly?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in Priority.

`prepareTopicEdits` doesn't call other methods.
I had to lower the search order to **5** from **10** for it to be picked up and ran first.